# Magento config.xml is not working to call layout.xml

Tags: php, xml, magento

I am trying to call a phtml page through layout.xml.. I have create a test.phtml page  and keep it in "C:\wamp\www\krishnendu\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\html" path.. my layout file is "catalogajax.xml" is kept in "C:\wamp\www\krishnendu\app\design\frontend\base\default\layout" and the code is:

```
<catalogajax_index_index>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="categoryajax.products" template="page/html/test.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalogajax_index_index>
</layout>
```

and my config.xml is in "C:\wamp\www\krishnendu\app\code\local" and like:

```
<config>    
    <modules>
        <Abc_CategoryAjax>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Abc_CategoryAjax>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <categoryajax>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Abc_CategoryAjax</module>
                    <frontName>categoryajax</frontName>
                </args>
            </categoryajax>
        </routers> 
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <categoryajax>
                    <file>catalogajax.xml</file>
                </categoryajax>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

What I find that layout.xml is not calling from config.xml..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used "categoryajax" as frontName, and using "catalogajax_index_index" as action in your catalogajax.xml.

That's why you are unable to see reflection.

Please change either frontName to "catalogajax" in config.xml

or change "catalogajax_index_index" to "categoryajax_index_index" in your catalogajax.xml.